# Checking if a string contains more than one type of character

Tags: python

Making program that creates a password using random characters from the string module. I'm trying to make sure the created password contains equal to or greater than 2 numbers and 2 punctuation.

Here's what I have so far:

```
from random import choice
from string import digits, punctuation, ascii_letters

password = []
everything = list(digits+punctuation+ascii_letters)

for i in range(10):
    password.append(choice(everything))
password = ''.join(password)
print(password)
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question?

Comment: You had a typo, `punctutation`, so I fixed it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! What's your question? Please [edit] to clarify. See [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do to check if the password has `at least 2 digits` and `at least 2 punctuations` -

```
from string import digits, punctuation

def check(password, d=2, p=2):
    num_digits = len([i for i in password if i in digits])
    num_punctuation = len([i for i in password if i in punctuation])
    return num_digits >= d and num_punctuation >= p

print(check('password@123'))
print(check('password@123#'))
print(check('password@123@'))
```

```
False
True
True
```

For longer strings, it would be more efficient to write a single for-loop however, since you only have 10 length passwords, let's just use 2 different list comprehensions.

Comment: Good effort but converting the password into a `set` means a valid password like `@1password@1` will fail because the set would only contain one '@' and one '1' even though there are two of them. ('2 digits' doesn't mean '2 different digits'.)

Comment: that is correct, cant believe i missed that. 4am blues. let me fix that.

Comment: FWIW, the OP didn't clarify if they are trying to (a) "generate valid passwords" or (b) "check passwords for validity". You've answered the question for (b) - which is fine but more useful to wait for OP to clarify first. (If you feel like, you can add a solution for (a) but answering questions which aren't well asked or don't provide further details in comments or edits, should be avoided on SO.)

Comment: The code OP provided was for (a) already, the first statement made by him was the general project he is working on (which has no relation what so ever to the problem he is trying to solve (b). That is mentioned as `i am trying to ...`. So I guess I interpreted the question as only (b) . Otherwise yes, I do understand the good practice of clarification before answering :)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying myself more. I'm trying to check the validity. What I've written above already creates a password, I'm just trying to have my code so that it makes those two criteria.

Comment: What I meant was - if the question is about "generating valid passwords" using those two rules, then the passwords can directly be **generated in a valid form** without needed a check/verification. Hint: the correct way to _generate_ those would be similar to how you _validated_ it ;-)

Comment: @v-MissedDenial So you want to _generate valid passwords_? You can use your generate-something-random method + validate using Akshay's method - until you get a valid password. **OR** you could directly generate a valid password.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @aneroid. You are absolutely right. I believe OP is trying to only check the generated passwords and not generate valid passwords - `I'm trying to make sure the created password contains ...`.

Comment: @v-MissedDenial I will request if you could update the question to make this more clearer thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either **generate** a random password (as you have) and then **validate** it using the answer Akshay provided. **OR** you can **directly generate a valid password**.

Here's a solution for the latter:

```py
import random
from string import digits, punctuation, ascii_letters

def generate(length=10):
    """all passwords generated are valid"""
    password = []
    password.extend(random.choices(digits, k=2))  # select 2 numbers
    password.extend(random.choices(punctuation, k=2))  # select 2 puncs
    # select the remaining from all 3 groups
    password.extend(random.choices(digits + punctuation + ascii_letters, k=length - 4))
    # shuffle the list of generated chars, and return
    random.shuffle(password)
    return ''.join(password)
```

Outputs:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     print(generate())
...
E3HT~]2]#=
"22|$B/=7y
+h9}A]$7Y9
v~K335?}9K
?!W*C4o%9*
```

(And you can add parameters for minimum digits, punctuation chars, etc. to make it more dynamic.)

Comment: Downside is that this will _usually_ generate passwords which have more than 2 digits and punc chars since they are both included in the last selection from `digits + punctuation + ascii_letters`. That may not be what you want. In which case, go with the "generate randomly first, then validate" solution.